# Easiest efficient way to zip output of hadoop mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, zip, gzip

I can compress mapreduce output to gzip with

```
"mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"
```

Will it be straightforward to implement zip codec for hadoop? Zip is container, but I need only one file per archive, so would it be easy to create `ZipCodec` with `CompressionCodec` interface?

Or, maybe there is an efficient way to convert `gz` files to `zip`s, since they can use same deflate algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No big deal, you can wrap a `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`.

You can do this by implementing your own codec, which is done by extending `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec`.

In this codec you wrap the java zip streams by extending `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream` respectively `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream`.

In the end you have to override the `createInputStream` and `createOutputStream` method and return a new instance of the wrapped streams there.

Still a bit of coding, I'm pretty sure there must be an already existing implementation somewhere (I may recall it also was in a Hadoop release years ago).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful directions.

Comment: @Thomas - Any examples possible?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas this is really helpful.