# Hadoop: Modify output file after it's written

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Summary: can I specify some action to be executed on each output file after it's written with hadoop streaming?

Basically, this is follow-up to [Easiest efficient way to zip output of hadoop mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988214/easiest-efficient-way-to-zip-output-of-hadoop-mapreduce/) question. I want for each key `X` its value written to `X.txt` file, compressed into `X.zip` archive. But when we write zip output stream, it's hard to tell something about a key or a name of resulting file, so we end up with `X.zip` archive containing `default-name.txt`.

It'd be very simple operation to rename archive contents, but where can I place it? What I don't want to do is download all zips from S3 and upload them back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a custom [MultipleOutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html):
**Basic use cases:**

- This class is used for a map reduce job with at least one reducer. The reducer wants to write data to different files depending on the actual keys. 
  It is assumed that a key (or value) encodes the actual key (value) and the desired location for the actual key (value).
- This class is used for a map only job. The job wants to use an output file name that is either a part of the input file name of the input data, or some derivation of it.
- This class is used for a map only job. The job wants to use an output file name that depends on both the keys and the input file name

You may also control which key goes to which reducer ([Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html))